# Passing an integer value from Applet to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, class, applet, jpanel

I'm currently working on a small school project. I've got to say I'm a beginner in Java, and I've got stuck on passing some data in Swing/AWT. What I'm trying to do is to pass a value from Java Applet to an instance of my sub class which extends JPanel. The problem I get is: "Cannot resolve method". Thanks in advance for help, here's some code snippet:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends Applet implements ActionListener{
    //Initializing all the necessary components.
    JPanel menu, draw;
    JButton createCircle, createRectangle, createPolygon, clearCanvas;

    public void init() {
        this.setLayout(null);
        [...]

        draw = new DrawingPanel();
        draw.setLayout(null);
        draw.setBounds(0, 70, getWidth(), getHeight());
        draw.setBorder(null);
        draw.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        createCircle = new JButton("Circle");
        createCircle.setBounds(10, 10, 50, 50);
        createCircle.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        createCircle.setBorder(null);
        createCircle.addActionListener(this);
        createCircle.setActionCommand("Circle");
        menu.add(createCircle);

        [...]

        add(menu);
        add(draw);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        switch (e.getActionCommand()) {
            case "Circle":
                draw.setMode(1);
                break;
        [...]
        }
    }
}
```

And the JPanel class code:

```
import javax.accessibility.Accessible;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel implements 
MouseListener, MouseWheelListener, MouseMotionListener{

    [...]

    Point tempPoint, tempPoint2;
    int mode=0;

    DrawingPanel(){
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    public void setMode(int a){
        mode = a;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (tempPoint!=null){
            g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.drawLine(tempPoint.x, tempPoint.y, tempPoint2.x, tempPoint2.y);
        }
    [...]
    }
```

Comment: Change `JPanel draw;` to `DrawingPanel draw;` You must declare the variable as a DrawingPanel type variable if you want it to be able to use DrawingPanel methods.

Comment: Since this is a school assignment, I won't go into why you should not be coding applets as it is a dead technology, but if you must code applets, use the Swing version, `JApplet`, not the AWT version, `Applet`. Also you really want to avoid using `null` layouts.

Comment: Ugh, stupid mistake. Thank you for pointing this out. So I've heard that the  Applet technology is dead, but can you tell me why?

Comment: Because browsers don't fully support them, and even Oracle, the force behind Java and applets, doesn't support them. And there are much better options available such as HTML5/CSS3/JavaScript and JavaFX/WebView.

Comment: Please see: [THIS](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web) Oracle blog article